# Stored Procedure with SimpleRepository

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic3, simplerepository

How to I execute a Stored Procedure with SimpleRepository and get a Typed List as a answer?
I'm using SubSonic 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
        StoredProcedure sproc = new StoredProcedure("SprocName", ProviderFactory.GetProvider(ConnectionStringName));

        string input= "input text";
        sproc.Command.AddParameter("input", input, DbType.String);

        return sproc.ExecuteTypedList<T>();
```

Comment: Delicious! Where did you find this?